# Does including icons for multiple screen sizes in an Android app impact the installed size

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-icons

When you include icons for multiple screen sizes in your Android application are the icons that don't apply to that screen size purged when the application is installed on a device? For example, if I have a tablet that has an xlarge screen that has a xhdpi density are the icons in the drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable-xhdpi folders purged when the application is installed (assuming drawable-xhdpi has all the necessary icons)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All resources in will be included in the apk. The apk *is* the installed application; there's no point at which the resources are copied elsewhere before running it. You can confirm this by installing your app on a Nexus 10, then [using adb to make it emulate other dpi targets](https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/cz5TxuoNDfG). Even though you've installed the apk when the device was at a xxhdpi, relaunching it at mdpi doesn't kick off another install, the mdpi resources are already there.

A solid strategy for reducing the size is to simply not use large images when they're not necessary. I use conservative 9-patches and substitute xml drawables for shapes when appropriate. If you've done everything you can and you're still concerned with the apk size, you can [create multiple apks that target different dpi points](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters).

Answer (score 1):

It has to have one of each of those icons in the apk.  So it will increase the size.

Comment: Yes, I know the APK size will increase. I'm talking about the installed size, after the APK has been exploded. Also, it doesn't "have" to have an icon of each size. You could have an application that has 1 xhdpi icon and the rest mdpi.

Comment: Sure you can.  But you weren't talking about that.  There is no such thing as an "installed size", the apk is not exploded until runtime.  the only thing that might be cached like that is dex files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will but you can use programs like [`OptiPng`](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) to compress your PNG Images so the size of the application wouldn't be affected much.